# The integral closure of Bezout domains in arbitrary field extensions is Prüfer?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

Let $R$ be a Bezout domain with quotient field $K$, $L$ an arbitrary extension field of $K$, and $\overline{R}$ the integral closure of $R$ in $L$. Is $\overline{R}$ a Prüfer domain? If the answer is negative, I wonder under what conditions it would be a Prüfer domain?

Comment: The answer is positive.

Comment: Please introduce a reference.

Comment: Which definition of Prufer are you using?